# JOptionPane Input for loop with two increments

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, joptionpane

Ok so I'm having trouble with the following loop. The intended goal of this loop is userinput[k] is a list of names that have already been alphabetically sorted in method. These names will then be presented in the InputDialog below, where a number that represents a degree will be entered.

I'm trying to match both the name and degree up. For example: In the loop, the first user input would be userinput[0]. I want the number input to then bee degree[0] and then so on....

The problem is how I store that input with the J incrementor. So the error I'm basically getting is the String degree[] = Integer......

```
for ( int k = 0;  k < userinput.length;  k++ ){      
     for (int j = 0; j < userinput.length; j++ ) {                    
         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the highest earned degree for the following person : " + userinput [ k ] +  "\n 1 = BS \n 2 = MS \n 3 = PhD");
         String degree[] = Integer.parseInt(input[]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need nested loops?  This makes you ask the question for the same person multiple (`userinput.length') times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
int[] degree = new int[userInput.length];
for(int k = 0; k < userInput.length; k++) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the highest earned degree for the following person : " + userinput [ k ] +  "\n 1 = BS \n 2 = MS \n 3 = PhD");
    degree[k] = Integer.parseInt(input);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for. Thanks for the help! I was thinking way to much about it.

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome. Use a single `for`-loop whenever you want to go through the array once, unless it's multidimensional. Otherwise each name will appear multiple times in the input dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to do?

> Assuming that you already declared userinput as an array of strings of
>   a certain size and assigned its values, and declared degree as array
>   of strings of the same size.

```
for ( int k = 0;  k < userinput.length;  k++ ){      
         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the highest earned degree for the following person : " + userinput [ k ] +  "\n 1 = BS \n 2 = MS \n 3 = PhD");
         degree[k] = input;
     }
}
```